# Animating Data Changes in Tibco Spotfire

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

This is my first post here, so please forgive me if I fail at etiquette somewhere along the way.

I am working on a POC dealing with animating a visualization within Tibco Spotfire 7.0 which will allow a user to see changes in data over time by iterating through a set of filters or by iterating through alterations to the data based on a pre-determined set of conditions. TIBCOmmunity already defines a custom tool for this purpose http://tibcoanalytics.com/spotfire/archive/totw/2011-01-16.html. However, it is my task to show that this can be done within an Iron Python script. The POC is rather simple in concept, I need an Action Control to move a point on a scatter plot around in a circle. Below is the Python I'm working with so far. The issue I am having is forcing Spotfire to update/refresh the visualization inside the loop. Help?

```
import time
import math
R = Rad; #parameter containing the radius of the circle
x_0 = xc; #parameter containing the center x coord
y_0 = yc; #parameter containing the center y coord

t=0.00
while t<(2*math.pi):
    x = R*(math.cos(t)) + x_0;
    y = R*(math.sin(t)) + y_0;
    t+=0.01
    Document.Properties['xc'] = x
    Document.Properties['yc'] = y
    #code to force the visualization/document to refresh/update goes here
    time.sleep(1/360)
```

Comment: I know it's an off-topic comment, but this is one of the most well-written first posts on Stack Overflow I've seen in a long time.

Comment: @ShotgunNinja definitely in this tag space :)

Comment: @Kaorie, I'm struggling to reproduce what you've done so far. is it possible for you to share a sanitized version of your analysis via dropbox or mega or something?

Comment: @ShotgunNinja Thanks!

Comment: @niko here is what I'm working with. There are 'print' statements in the script for debugging purposes that I didn't post here earlier. Other than that it's all here. No sanitizing required, which was the purpose of doing the POC in this fashion.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/uwcc8xfimdgllxj/DataAnimationPOC.dxp?dl=0

Comment: ah I see! I was running into the same issue. it's not that the visualization is not being updated, actually, but that Spotfire isn't really friendly with `time.sleep()`. you can see what's actually happening if you change your delay to 1 second: the app freezes! I have a workaround/hack that I've made but it's not super simple. give me a bit to modify the DXP for consumption and I'll share it here.

Comment: just a thought -- if you're handy with IronPython you *could* try to spawn a new thread and run your script there. not sure if this will get any different result inside of Spotfire, though, or if it will work on the web player.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this does not directly answer your question but provides you with a method of creating a timer that can interact with document properties. sorry that I don't have time to provide an explicit answer. as such feel free not to mark it accepted -- maybe someone else has a better one.

the reason that your code doesn't work is because the IronPython engine locks Spotfire until execution is completed. you're not far off in assuming that the visualization doesn't update: in fact the entire application doesn't update! you can test this as I mentioned in my comment by setting the sleep value to 1 second.

I created [this DXP](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18835606/Javascript%20and%20IronPython%20Interaction.dxp) some time ago to illustrate how to allow IronPython and Javascript code to interact with each other inside of textareas. the **IP->JS** page should give you some clues on how to build your animation solution.

what's going on behind the scenes here:

1. a Spotfire Property Control (Input area) inside of a `<div>` allows the user to enter text
2. a Javascript function called `update` runs periodically: `var timer = setInterval(update, 1000);`
3. the `update` function uses JQuery to access the input area via its parent `<div>`: `var text_in = $("#input_container").text();`
4. `update` finally replaces the text in an "output" container `<div>` with the modified text: `$("#output_container").html(rainbowize(text_in));`

you can modify this example to use JQuery to output to a document property-linked input area. in other words, use the Javascript timer `setInterval()` instead of `time.sleep()`.

I hope I've done a decent job of explaining that. let me know if it was unclear :)

Comment: I will adapt your method to my project. If it is functional, I will post the final and explicit solution as a comment here and mark your solution as accepted. Thanks for your assistance here!

Comment: Below is a snippet of the code that finally did the trick for me. missing portions of the code are denoted by `...` as this is drawn from a much larger .js that defines a clickable button in a Spotfire text area. Upon request I can post the dxp. This project ended up proving that Spotfire7.0 cannot handle a lot of render requests per second, but at a rate of 1 per second, the animation works just fine!

Comment: `R=Number($("#Rad").text().trim());
x_0=Number($("#x_0").text().trim());
y_0=Number($("#y_0").text().trim());
t=0.00;
var spin = function(){
 if (t<(2*Math.PI))
 {  
  x = R*(Math.cos(t)) + x_0;
  y = R*(Math.sin(t)) + y_0;
  //document.getElementById('mySpotfireControlx').firstChild.value = x;
  $("#mySpotfireControlx input").val(x).blur();
  //document.getElementById('mySpotfireControly').firstChild.value = y;
  $("#mySpotfireControly input").val(y).blur();
  t+=0.01;
 };
}

`...

`function mouseUp() {`
...
 `t=0.00;
 setInterval(spin,1000)
}
`...